# About method call and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance

1. If I set `private` for `getMoney()` method instead of `public`, it can't accessed by `money.getMoney()` in MyMoney class.
2. In HeMoney class, I can call `getMoney()` directly without creating Money object since HeMoney class is derived from Money class.
3. In HeMoney class , I can override `getSheMoney()` since both class (HeMoney and SheMoney) are derived from Money class.

   ```
   public class Money {
        public int money = 50;

        public Money(int m) {
            money = m;
        }

        public int getMoney() {
            return money;
        }
   }

   public class MyMoney {
           int my;  
           Money mymoney = new money(100);
           my = mymoney.getMoney();          
   }

   public class HeMoney extends Money {
       public int hemoney = 0 ;
       hemoney = getMoney();

       @Override
       public int getSheMoney() {
            return hemoney;
        } 
   }

   public class SheMoney extends Money {
       public int shemoney = 70;

        public SheMoney(int m) {
            shemoney = m;
        }

        public int getSheMoney() {
            return shemoney;
        }
   }
   ```

Since I'm a beginner, I want to know whether my knowledge is correct.

Comment: I read this line `I just use a simple name for the method and declare it without private modifier.` many times, I just don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: 2. Better use the `protected` modifier.

Comment: You can't override a method from a sibling. Only from a ancestor. Why don't you write the code for all these 3 cases, compile and test it?

Comment: 1 - No, you don't need to do any of those things to call `getArea` on a `Rectangle`. Just construct one and call the method on it - e.g. `new Rectangle(arguments).getArea()`

Comment: @user3437460 Sorry. Since I'm not a native speaker of English, I can't write the English sentences smoothly.

Comment: @vul18 No problem, but if you want your questions to be answered, you may want to make it easy for us to understand....

Comment: @vul18 the beauty of code is that it's understandable whetever your language is. So, instead of describing code, you could just post it, and everyone would understand what you mean.

Comment: I have edited again.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure what did you mean by saying "outside the code", but if you want to access that from out side of that Class you have to use "rectone.getArea()" and you have to declare that method as public or protected.
2. Its not clear whether you want "call" or "declare" that method n subclass.
   If you want to call that method then there is no need to extend the super class.
   If you want to declare that method, extend the super class and declare it with same signature.
3. Yes . you can override it in MountainBike class and its independent of RoadBike class

Comment: I think about words "outside the code" too. I feel Vul18 reverse (in this beginning question, ok) first and second part of tv serial: when I want to call a method need create object. It is reverse of thinking. I'm no native english too, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

1. extending access (idea 1. "derive and made public") is not always elegant, may breaks rules.
2. lowering access level (discuses in subquestion 2) marking as private is prohibited by compiler (interesting long discussion: in Java prohibited, in C++ not)

I feel (unclear) procedural thinking in question, translated to Java: `want CALL then create object` is procedural thinking. OOP is `I have an OBJECT and can call`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

1. Yes you need to make object for calling any of method from other classes.
   Example :- You have class 'Person' and other class 'Vehicle' .This vehicle has method ride, person want to call ride , he has first have object Vehicle.
2. When you extend / subclass of any class , you inherit public and protected methods. So, you can directly call it in  child class , as it is calling its own method.
   Now , Other class Car extends the Vehicle , which means car is vehicle so car can call ride automatically.
3. Now there is class Train extends Vehicle , now if Train wants that it can ride in other way from Vehicle. It wants to ride on rails ,so Train can write its own version. That is called overriding.